# How to refactor and discover dependencies when doing BDD

Tags: refactoring, tdd, mocking, bdd

Doing BDD means going from top to bottom, so we write test for top level feature first. Now to setup a test you usually need to set up some mocks instead of real deps. How do you know what dependemcies are required, what kind of services you need? I can't make up how to define dependencies on this level. In classical TDD bottom up it was as simple as refactoring your existing impl into dependent objects.

Does BDD and mocking means that we are required to have complete dependencies graph made up and roughly designed upfront?

What about refactoring then? It seems taht there is no place for breaking your impl into dependencies any more as you have those defined already.

Eg I have a timed cache feature to implement.
My tests should be:

- return value via storage call if not cached
- return value with no storage call if cached
- return value via storage call if timeout exceeded

Does it mean I need to have all my potential dependencies identified and mocks prepared? And should I verify values returned from my xall, or just dependencies calls expected?

Comment: Here BDD means Behavior-Driven-Development, not Binary-Decision-Diagram.  (This is to clarify why I have canceled agf's tag renaming.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that you may be over-thinking this a bit. When things seem really confusing, I usually remind myself to take a step back and review the basics. First, I want to only do the minimum needed to satisfy a requirement.  I don't really care whether there are going to be many dependencies in the system that I'm not yet aware of, so I write my tests in the simplest possible way.  If I see a need for a dependency, I'll throw in a mock and support the minimum interface needed to allow my test to run.  If the system needs to expand or support an additional dependency later on, I can extend the mock, or even replace it with something specific to the next test that I write. I might also extend a test, or even write a new test to satisfy new requirements as they become known and/or clear to me.

Refactoring is just a fancy way of saying that I intend to change something.  This could be to  optimise or otherwise improve the design, or it could be because I see a need to break out new interfaces and dependencies. In that case, I start by writing a change into my tests, or possibly even write a new test which may or may not replace an existing test.  When that is done, I go to my code.

Top-down or bottom-up, the fundamentals are essentially the same. The question is really when dependencies will become self-evident, and then determining a strategy to deal with them.  When you feel a need to break something out, I'd suggest a very short spike.  Let the idea take shape, and roll it about in front of your eyes while throwing questions at it.  If it feels correct to pursue the idea, write tests to deal with the problems your spike presents you, then code from there.

I sometimes find myself getting the urge to create a huge array of mocks to deal with every possible dependency contingency that I can think of, and every time I come back to repeating "K.I.S.S.", "Y.A.G.N.I.", and "Make it work, then make it work better", over and over in my head until I get the message that I can't really afford to get stuck because I'm trying to think too far ahead.

Whether you TDD, BDD, or use any other approach, keeping things simple and minimal is the key to ensuring that you don't tackle too much at once. This is probably the most important thing to remember.  If it seems too difficult to visualize, then ask yourself if you have a "requirements smell" which suggests you need to break things down a little further. Can you break the "story" down into a set of smaller stories that encompass the whole.

I know that I've not necessarily answered the question you asked directly, however I thought it worth writing in this way, as it's been my experience that dependencies and refactorings become self evident when the tasks are small, and limited to only a single feature or two, while the opposite occurs when the tasks are too generalized and left open to interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

With BDD, you aren't working at the unit level (i.e. one public method of one public class). You are working at the system level. Therefore you will want to mock **everything outside the system boundary**. This means that storage system or external system will be mocked: files, databases, services, etc.

Furthermore, you will want to make sure that your specs prove themselves repeatedly, so like *TDD*, you will want to mock out any non-deterministic element. This means in particular the **clock** and **Random** functions, but could also mean a weather service (which of course overlaps with the extraneous elements you wish to mock) or something like it.

As for how to discover them, there are two possibilities I see, both of which you can use. First is to draw a system diagram, which is basically a box which represents everything in your **[SUT](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html)**. Then draw anything you know you will need that falls into one of the above categories. That's what you need to mock.

The other technique is to code until you fall onto a dependency you must mock, and then refactor with the **[Bridge Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx)** so as not to be dependent on it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dont drive design with top level (integration?)-test.

Use them to know when your feature is complete and drive out the internals of your code using standard TDD practices.

A bit short but I hope you understand what I mean.